# Could not validate the All type conditions using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need one help. I am unable to validate properly the conditions present inside if statement using JavaScript.I am explaining my code below.

```
<?php if($_REQUEST['ids']!=""){ ?>
var isEdit=true;
var edithidnCouponimage=document.getElementById('hidnCouponimage').value;
var edithidnLogoimage=document.getElementById('hidnLogoimage').value;
 <?php }else{ ?>
 var isEdit=false;
var edithidnCouponimage='';
var edithidnLogoimage='';
 <?php } ?>
if(isEdit==false){
  if(!backFileInput.files[0].name.match(/.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$/i)){
  alert('Please select jpg/jpeg/png type image for coupon image');
  return;
        }else if(!logoFileInput.files[0].name.match(/.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$/i)){
            alert('Please select jpg/jpeg/png type image for coupon logo');
            return;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
}else{
   $('#btncouponsubmit').removeAttr("disabled")
   $('#blankImagediv').css('display', 'block');
   $('#nonblankimagediv').css('display', 'none');
}
```

Here my problem is when first `if statement` is true and inside it its checking both `if statement` if those are not true it should come back from parent `if statement` and should enter into `else part` for the checking `display block/none` but its not happening like that once its entering into first if statement its not entering into `else part`.Please help me.

Comment: why not just replace return true with the block from else statement? You can simply move those 3 line into a function if you don't want to duplicate code

Comment: @JurijJazdanov : Did not get you.

Comment: From the question I understood that if isEdit is false, and both if statements are false you must do the same as the isEdit was true. If im right, you can just replace return true with that block

Comment: yes.I need to get into the main else part.

Comment: then why you don't just replace return true with the same code? https://jsfiddle.net/r70du61z/

Comment: There will be more code thats why.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145952/discussion-between-jurij-jazdanov-and-subhra).

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to copy else block for your need:

```
if(isEdit==false){
    if(!backFileInput.files[0].name.match(/.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$/i)){
        alert('Please select jpg/jpeg/png type image for coupon image');
        return;
    }else if(!logoFileInput.files[0].name.match(/.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$/i)){
        alert('Please select jpg/jpeg/png type image for coupon logo');
        return;
    }else{
        $('#btncouponsubmit').removeAttr("disabled")
        $('#blankImagediv').css('display', 'block');
        $('#nonblankimagediv').css('display', 'none');
        return true;
    }
}else{
    $('#btncouponsubmit').removeAttr("disabled")
    $('#blankImagediv').css('display', 'block');
    $('#nonblankimagediv').css('display', 'none');
}
```

If you don't want to duplicate code move the duplicate part to a function

```
if(isEdit==false){
  if(!backFileInput.files[0].name.match(/.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$/i)){
    alert('Please select jpg/jpeg/png type image for coupon image');
    return;
  }else if(!logoFileInput.files[0].name.match(/.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$/i)){
    alert('Please select jpg/jpeg/png type image for coupon logo');
    return;
  }else{
    enable();
    return true;
  }
}else{
  enable();
}

function enable() {
  $('#btncouponsubmit').removeAttr("disabled")
  $('#blankImagediv').css('display', 'block');
  $('#nonblankimagediv').css('display', 'none');
}
```

Comment: If I will have any `else if statement` after parent `if` statement then what to do.

Comment: @subhra I'm confused, just write them before else statement. Please move to the chat, or we will spam